# Counting number of requests per second generated by JMeter client

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter

This is how application setup goes -

- 2 c4.8xlarge instances
- 10 m4.4xlarge jmeter clients generating load. Each client used 70 threads

While conducting load test on a simple GET request (685 bytes size page). I came across issue of reduced throughput after some time of test run. Throughput of about 18000 requests/sec is reached with 700 threads, remains at this level for 40 minutes and then drops. Thread count remains 700 throughout the test. I have executed tests with different load patterns but results have been same.

[image: Throughput]

The application response time considerably low throughout the test -

[image]

According to ELB monitor, there is reduction in number of requests (and I suppose hence the lower throughput ) -
[image]

There are no errors encountered during test run. I also set connect timeout with http request but yet no errors.

I discussed this issue with aws support at length and according to them I am not blocked by any network limit during test execution.

Given number of threads remain constant during test run, what are these threads doing? Is there a metrics I can check on to find out number of requests generated (not Hits/sec) by a JMeter client instance?

Testplan - http://justpaste.it/qyb0

Comment: Can you send share the JMX file? At least the setup.  Do you have it loop forever?

Comment: I don't have loop, updated my question with link to test plan

Comment: Did you check common system issues, e.g. jmeter's own memory size (i.e. maybe it spends more time doing GC than it should). Second common problem is when JMeter exhausts ports faster than they become available after TIME_WAIT (so reducing TIME_WAIT and increasing number of available ports would help). Second issue could also be applicable to the server side.

Comment: I would also try to see if half of the jmeters produce half of the load (i.e. if with 1 jmeter the throughput remains the same, problem is likely on server side; if it is reduced by half, than on jmeter).

Comment: Since I don't get java.net.BindException probable port is not an issue.

Comment: There is 4 GB of heap allocated to jmeter instances. When using half of the jmeter instances then I should see half of the throughput (ideally) is not it? Why should this be a problem with jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following Test Elements:

- [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
- and especially [DNS Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) as it might be the situation where all your threads are hitting only one c4.8xlarge instance while the remaining one is idle. See [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) article for explanation and details.

Comment: HTTP Cache Manager and DNS Cache Manager are in place. I updated question with link to test plan

Comment: I have also carried out test with out ELB and results have shown same pattern of drop in throughput after some time of test run